# Listing all builds of a Jira project performed by Bamboo

Tags: version-control, build, jira, issue-tracking, bamboo

I have recently integrated my Jira Server (4.3.x) with my Bamboo Server (3.1.x) and Subversion server (Collabnet 1.6.x). When I click on the build tab of a project on Jira, it only lists those builds that are linked with a project issue. But I have many builds that are not linked to any of my issues, therefore, those builds are not listed in the build tab of Jira. How can I tell Jira to list me ALL the builds of my project, not only those linked with project issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to list all builds of a Jira project performed by Bamboo, on the build tab of a project in jira.

Answer (score 1):

There are pages on Atlassian's JIRA and Bamboo documentation wikis about doing this see: [Browsing a Project's Bamboo Builds](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Browsing+a+Project%27s+Bamboo+Builds) (JIRA 4.3 specific) and [Integrating Bamboo with JIRA](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO031/Integrating+Bamboo+with+JIRA) (Bamboo 3.1 specific).

Comment: I've seen these pages before. As the first link mentions: "the list of the builds which are related to the project, i.e. builds that have issues from the project linked to them ...". This is the feature I do not like and wanna know how can scape from it?